# Applying a function to a list object

Tags: python, pandas, list, function

I have a multi variable function:

```
def particle_range(row, energy=eng_list):
    r = 0.01* (((row['mass'] * energy)/(144 * row['projectile'] ** 2 * row['element'] * math.log((2195 * energy)/row['ionisation']))))
        return r
```

Every time the function is run, the same energy variable will be input. This is a list of energies:

```
eng_list = [0.01,0.02,0.03, 0.04, 0.05]
```

Every time the function is run, a difference dataframe will be passed through. Each dataframe contains a single row of data. Each column in this row is an input to particle_range().

I want the output to be a list, which is the function applied to each element in the list, `eng_list`

I apply a dataframe to this. Where df is given below:

```
data = [['natMo-a', 98, 43, 2, 9.2, 42]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['reaction', 'mass', 'element', 'projectile', 'density', 'ionisation'])
```

I then run `df.apply(particle_range)`

When I run this I get an error:

```
TypeError: ("can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I have then tried running

`df.apply(particle_range, axis=1, energy=np.array(energy=eng_list)))`

This returns the error:

```
TypeError: Required argument 'object' (pos 1) not found
```

Comment: you should do `df.apply(particle_range, energy=np.array(energy=eng_list))`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Would I need to make any changes to the function itself?

Comment: most likely yes for vectorization. I can't quite say from your function what you are trying to do. Also, as you want to apply on rows, `df.apply(particle_range, axis=1, energy=np.array(...))`

Comment: @QuangHoang I've edited my euqation to try to make it more clear.

Comment: `energy=np.array(eng_list)`. Also, use np.log inside the function instead of math.log.